What does the "collapse of Joseph" in Amos 6:6 refer to?
In Amos 6:6 we have (NASB):

Who drink wine from sacred bowls While they anoint themselves with the finest of oils—Yet they have not grieved over the collapse of Joseph.

I'm specifically interested in the referent of "over the collapse of Joseph".
The Hebrew is:

הַשֹּׁתִים בְּמִזְרְקֵי יַיִן, וְרֵאשִׁית שְׁמָנִים יִמְשָׁחוּ; וְלֹא נֶחְלוּ, עַל-שֵׁבֶר יוֹסֵף.

With the relevant phrase, עַל-שֵׁבֶר יוֹסֵף
The LXX translates the phrase as ἐπὶ τῇ συντριβῇ Ιωσηφ, συντριβῇ means crushing or ruin.
I immediately thought of when Joseph's brothers sold him.  If that's the metaphorical referent, then how does that fit with the actual time and place in Amos?  Why is Amos pointing to the selling into slavery?
The two previous clauses are in contrast.  "Drinking from bowls" would have referred to the luxurious action of so much wine that one used a large bowl and not a little cup.  And "the finest oils" would have also been the same amount of luxury.
So, I get the contrast between luxury and slavery.  But I don't think Amos was referring to Joseph's sale.  I think it's a metaphor for something that was happening in Amos's day.  What was that?
What does the metaphor of the "collapse of Joseph" in Amos 6:6 refer to, and how does it fit into Amos's time and place?

Collapse of Joseph:
Three possible meanings:

In light of Genesis 40:23, it could represent the betrayal and
disappointment Joseph felt when forgotten by the cupbearer,
paralleling the Israelites’ neglect of their covenant with God.
Genesis 37:25 describes the moment when Joseph’s brothers sat down to eat after throwing Joseph into a pit. Amos may be trying to illustrate the indifference and heartlessness of Joseph’s brothers, who were able to sit down and eat while their brother was in the pit, showing no concern for his suffering.
Psalms 80:1 uses “Joseph” to refer to the kingdoms of Judah and
Israel collectively. Thus, Amos could be warning both kingdoms of
their impending downfall due to their shared indifference and
moral failures.

According to the Pulpit Commentary:

The coming ruin of the ten tribes affects them not; in their selfish
voluptuousness they have no sympathy with calamity and suffering, and
shut their eyes to coming evil. "The affliction of Joseph" is probably a proverbial expression derived from the narratives in Genesis 37:25, etc., and Genesis 40:14, 23 (comp. Genesis 42:21). Amos 6:6


Genesis 37:25: And they sat down to eat a meal. Then they lifted
their eyes and looked, and there was a company of Ishmaelites, coming
from Gilead with their camels, bearing spices, balm, and myrrh, on
their way to carry them down to Egypt.

Genesis 40:14, 23: But remember me when it is well with you, and
please show kindness to me; make mention of me to Pharaoh, and get me
out of this house.
Yet the chief butler did not remember Joseph, but forgot him.

Genesis 42:21: Then they said to one another, “We are truly
guilty concerning our brother, for we saw the anguish of his soul
when he pleaded with us, and we would not hear; therefore this
distress has come upon us.”


Overall, the “collapse of Joseph” refers to the moral decay of the Israelite society, which the people were ignoring in favor of their own comfort and luxury. This fits the global message of Amos. Amos called for repentance, warning the people that their disregard for the poor and needy, despite their own wealth and prosperity, would lead to their destruction.
Their indifference would lead to their eventual downfall. Perhaps this indifference is likened to the heartlessness of Joseph’s brothers. Their ability to sit down and eat while their brother was in the pit demonstrates a shocking level of indifference and heartlessness, showing no concern for his suffering. This indifference to suffering is a great offense to God.
Barnes' Notes on the Bible says:

But - (And) they are not grieved - (Literally, “grieve not
themselves,”) admit no grief, shut out all grief, “for the affliction” (literally, “breach”) of “Joseph.” The name of the patriarch, Ephraim’s father, recalled his suffering from his brethren . His brethren cast him into a “pit without water” Genesis 37:24, probalby an empty leaking well, (much as was that into which Jeremiah Jeremiah 38:6 was cast,) damp, fetid, and full of loathsome creatures. They “saw the anguish of his soul when he besought them, and would not hear” Genesis 42:21. But what did they? “They sat down to eat bread” Genesis 37:25. So did these rich men deal with all their brethren, all Ephraim. They suffered not in, or with, any sufferings, present or future, of individuals or the whole. “Cast off thought,” “cast off care,” is the motto of sensualists and of the worldly; “seize joyous the present hour, and leave the future,” said the pagan . This was the effect of their luxury and life of sense.


Psalms 80:1 refers to both the kingdoms of Judah and Israel as Joseph. Amos may also be referring to both the kingdoms of Judah and Israel as Joseph.


Psalms 80:1 - Give ear, O Shepherd of Israel, You who lead Joseph like a
flock; You who dwell between the cherubim, shine forth!

Henry's Complete Commentary on the Bible puts it well:

They had no concern at all for the interests of the church of God, and
of the nation, that were sinking and going to decay: They are not
grieved for the affliction of Joseph; the church of God, including
both the kingdoms of Judah and Israel (which are called Joseph,Psalms 80:1), was in distress, invaded, insulted, and broken in upon. As to
their own kingdom which they were entrusted with the government of,
the affairs of which they were directors of, the peace of which they
were the conservators of, great breaches were made upon it, upon its
peace and welfare; and they were so besotted that they were not aware
of them, so indulgent of their pleasures that they never laid them to
heart, and had such an aversion to the thing called business that they
were in no care or concern to get them repaired. It is all one to them
whether the nation sink or swim, so that they can but lie at ease and
live in pleasure. Particular persons that belonged to Joseph were in
affliction, and they took no cognizance of their case of the wrongs
and hardships they sustained and the troubles they were in, nor took
any care to relieve them, and right them, contrary to the temper of
holy Job, who, when he was in prosperity, wept with him that was in
misery and his soul was grieved for the poor,Job 30:25. Some think that, in calling the afflicted church Joseph, there is an allusion to the story of Pharaoh's butler, who, when he preferred to give the cup again into his master's hand, remembered not Joseph, but forgot him,Genesis 40:21; Genesis 40:23. Thus they drank wine in bowls, but
were not grieved for the affliction of Joseph. Note, Those are
commonly careless of the troubles of others who are set upon their own
pleasures; and it is a great offence to God when his church is in
affliction and we are not grieved for it, nor lay it to heart.





References




[1]
Amos 6 Pulpit Commentary. (n.d.). https://biblehub.com/commentaries/pulpit/amos/6.htm


[2]
Amos 6 Barnes’ notes. (n.d.). https://biblehub.com/commentaries/barnes/amos/6.htm


[3]
Amos 6 - Henry’s complete commentary on the Bible - Bible Commentaries - StudyLight.org. (n.d.). StudyLight.org. https://www.studylight.org/commentaries/eng/mhm/amos-6.html#verses-1




+1 This is well done.  The references to Genesis 37:25 and 42:21 are especially helpful in a midrash way.  Placing those two verses side by side speaks quite poignantly to the Amos text.  Thank you.

"Joseph" refers to the two "half-tribes of Joseph" namely Ephraim and Manasseh. These were the core of the 10 northern tribes often referred to as "Israel" while the two southern tribes were called "Judah" (including Judah and Benjamin).
Amos 5:16

Hate evil and love good,
and let justice prevail at the gate; Then it may be that the Lord, the God of hosts,
will have pity on the remnant of Joseph.

The prophet warns the northern tribes to repent so that the remnant may be saved from Assyrian captivity.

Those who lie on beds of ivory,
and lounge upon their couches; Eating lambs taken from the flock,
and calves from the stall; 5 Who improvise to the music of the harp,
composing on musical instruments like David, 6 Who drink wine from bowls,
and anoint themselves with the best oils,
but are not made ill by the collapse of Joseph; 7 Therefore, now they shall be the first to go into exile,
and the carousing of those who lounged shall cease.

The collapse of Joseph in this case refers to the destruction of the northern confederation of Israel. The beds of ivory are a reference to the royal court of the House of Ahab, famous for its opulence. (1 Kings 22:39) "They shall be the first to go into exile" refers to the Assyria's forced exile of the northern tribes. The prophet predicts that the carousing of the northern elites will be quieted when the Assyrians take them into captivity.

Joseph is one of the alternative names of the Northern Kingdom. The ten tribes of Israel. In the previous chapter, the prophet wrote:
4 For this is what the LORD says to the house of Israel: “Seek Me and live!
5 Do not seek Bethel or go to Gilgal; do not journey to Beersheba,for Gilgal will surely go into exile, and Bethel will come to nothing.a
6 Seek the LORD and live, or He will sweep like fire through the house of Joseph; it will devour everything, with no one at Bethel to extinguish it.
Amos highlights the injustice and exploitation of the poor and needy by the rich. The nation split from Judah in response to the oppression by the king Solomon. The new rulers became as bad as the son of David. History went full circle.
1 Then Rehoboam went to Shechem, for all Israel had gone there to make him king. 2 When Jeroboam son of Nebat heard about this, he was stilla in Egypt where he had fled from King Solomon and had been living ever since.
3 So they sent for Jeroboam, and he and the whole assembly of Israel came to Rehoboam and said,
4 “Your father put a heavy yoke on us. But now you should lighten the burden of your father’s service and the heavy yoke he put on us, and we will serve you.” (1 Kins 12)
11 Then the LORD said to Solomon, “Because you have done this and have not kept My covenant and My statutes, which I have commanded you, I will tear the kingdom away from you and give it to your servant.
12 Nevertheless, for the sake of your father David, I will not do it during your lifetime; I will tear it out of the hand of your son.
13 Yet I will not tear the whole kingdom away from him. I will give one tribe to your son for the sake of My servant David and for the sake of Jerusalem, which I have chosen.” (1 Kings 11)
Another judgement was unavoidable.
